# C++ libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion zsh: abort

Tags: c++

```cpp
void readDataset(ifstream &in, Results results[], int &size) {
    
    // Rows of data per rider
    const int dataLength = 5;
    string line;
    int num;
    // Execute a loop until EOF (End of File)
    while (in) {
 
        // Read a Line from File
        getline(in, line);
        num = std::stoi(line);
        cout << num << endl;
        // results[size].bibNumber = stoi(line);
        // getline(in, line);
        // results[size].name = line;
        // getline(in, line);
        // results[size].distance = std::stod(line);
        // getline(in, line);
        // results[size].time = line;
        size++;

    }
 
    // Close the file
    in.close();
}
```

I keep getting the following error `libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion zsh: abort`

I am trying to convert the line being read to an int.
The input file contains this

10

John Smith

122.0

05:40:52

Comment: `John Smith` is not a number.  When you try to turn it into one, that gives you the exception.

Comment: The value of 10 is being passed first?

Comment: To clarify, as of right now I believe the value of 10 is being stored into a string, and I am trying to convert it to an int.

Comment: @BrandonABustamante But the evidence is that you are incorrect in that belief, no? To fix bugs you have to learn to stop making assumptions about your code. The bug is evidence that your assumptions might be wrong.

Comment: @BrandonABustamante Put it another way, test your assumptions, Use a debugger, or at least add the line `std::cout << '|' << line << '|' << '\n';` to your code to find out what is really in the string.